# How to check if mouse is pressed (like an event)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a beginner to unity and I need to know how to detect when the mouse has went down

My script is parented to the camera (Because it is a camera script) and I need to know when the mouse button goes down so I can start to move the camera.

I also need to know when it moves, or goes up.

Comment: Also, I know that Input.GetMouseButton(1) exists, but I need to have it as an event.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [New Input System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuide.html) for this, it's got a little bit of a learning curve but has exactly what you are looking for as [it is entierly based around input events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Events.html).

There is a good explination [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Actions.html). You'll want to use the `performed` event of an input action, which is a regular event you can subscribe your functions to.

---

The `performed` event will corespond to whatever you set the action to be triggered by, for example the press down of a button if you set it so, or could be the press and release of a button.

So like:

```
cameraMoveAction.performed +=
    (_) =>
    {
        // move the camera
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

You could specify, when exactly mouse button click should be detected. The most logical case is using UI. So [here you are](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html).

Comment: I need a to detect a simple mouse down for a camera script (no ui or objects), just a simple mouse down on anywhere in the screen (I would prefer the right mouse button)

Comment: Well, there seems to be no other way than writing your own event in this case. I won't reinvent the wheel: [someone already asked this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/879156/how-would-i-detect-a-right-click-with-an-event-tri.html).